# Sealed lead-acid battery UPS indoor?

Tags: ups, lead-acid

I bought a BX700UI APC UPS for my linux arm server setup (40 watts) to protect it from power cut. - I have the server in the bedroom is it dangerous to have such an Ups in a small bedroom? - Thinking of gases?

Comment: Yes probably, If bedroom has no windows that are opened regularly. But it's not like the battery will spew hydrogen willy nilly.

Comment: @Indraneel To quote another user "That's hardly an answer, without hard data." How can you say that it is dangerous? Remember, "This is an EE site after all, we all need numbers!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Valve regulated lead
>   acid (VRLA) batteries and modular battery cartridges
>   (MBC) do not require special battery rooms and are
>   suitable for use in an office environment. Air changes
>   designed for human occupancy normally exceed the
>   requirements for VRLA and MBC ventilation.

[Ref](https://www.apc.com/salestools/SADE-5TNQZQ/SADE-5TNQZQ_R3_EN.pdf)

Also there is a little known fact that Hydrogen will not explode with O2 unless it exceeds the lower explosive level, LEL concentration of 4%,  then the probability rise above 0% at this threshold with a spark.

Compare generation of volume of gas from a faulty battery and faulty OVP and failed charger safety ( triple-mode failure).

### background and my logic

How much gas volume can an SLA battery generate compared to humans breathing out toxic carbon monoxide (CO)?  not much.

Yet a vented lead acid battery, which can generate 60x more than a SLA is unsafe, if overcharged .

For a small bedroom, this would need a lot of batteries to generate 4% H2 from overcharge failures and H2 generation,  given convection flow of air needed for humans to not asphyxiate from CO breathing. An SLA battery is unlikely to create this amount of H2 with a battery fault compared to the flow of CO from breathing out.  It may also trigger UPS battery fail alarm if this condition were detected.

Comment: I'm not a geek but is it a "Valve regulated lead acid" that is in my ups? - https://www.apc.com/shop/my/en/products/APC-Back-UPS-700VA-230V-AVR-IEC-Sockets/P-BX700UI

Comment: @ReneMortensen Yes, I believe so. My UPS had the battery installed on its side, so it is also probably a gel or mat. The cheapest SLA (with valve) are in the small cheap 4V batteries in rechargeable flashlights etc. It may be wise to keep them properly oriented during charging. I've never had one leak, but I don't know if they are gel/mat based too. You can see the valve on the top, sometimes.

Comment: So in general it's not dangerous to use in a bedroom as i understand? :)

Comment: Correct. If air flow is safe for humans , SLA's won't make it unsafe. yet not so for Flooded cell types.

Comment: @ReneMortensen No, that interpretation is not right. The valve exists to prevent explosion, not to prevent H2 from escaping. Actually, the valve exists to allow H2 to escape and prevent explosion. How much H2 depends on acid and charging stuff. As I said, we need numbers to quantify all that.

Comment: @ReneMortensen but in general, it may be ok, if you open the windows once in a while, room has cross ventilation etc... Maybe it's all unnecessary, but one can never know without the .... numbers. Look at it this way.. if too much H2 is produced, the acid would dry up before warranty expires. And the UPS has a dedicated charge controller for that exact battery. So maybe assume it's all safe as long as the UPS circuit works as expected.

Comment: Indraneel Sunnyskyguy Just told me that it is NOT dangerous in general ... - But what data do you need because I can get it? - But when there is a generalrule that says "Valve regulated lead acid (VRLA) batteries" do not require special battery rooms and are suitable for use in an office environment. Can't I see why you keep saying that there may be a problem?

Comment: @ReneMortensen There is no problem. H2 is not produced in normal use, only during over charging, which should not happen in an UPS. So if you consider that it's safe, then it's safe.

Comment: @Indraneel is taking an approach of mistrusting APC's safety design circuits for over voltage protection of charging the SLA battery.   The quote I gave, comes from ATC , the leader in UPS designs, with Safety certs. A DIY design may not be so safe.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Yes, that is spot on. However, as we know, bottom of the range UPS, even APC UPS, may have quality control issues. There have been recalls in the past. Your reference does touch upon these safety features (and safety requirements) which exist in APC UPS. My APC UPS is made in China. Not saying it is badly made, it's working fine for a decade.

Answer (score 0):

In normal operation it should not emit any gasses, the sealed lead acid batteries may occasionally vent a very small quantity of hydrogen during charging, but so does your digestive tract.

Comment: That's hardly an answer, without hard data.

Comment: I also do not assume that Ups charges more when it is fully charged once unless power is interrupted? - But maybe it is designed to discharge and charge the battery?

Comment: @ReneMortensen I doubt it. What would happen if there is a power outage while the UPS was discharging the battery?

Comment: What data do you need Indraneel ? https://www.apc.com/shop/my/en/products/APC-Back-UPS-700VA-230V-AVR-IEC-Sockets/P-BX700UI

Comment: I open the window in the room daily when I go to the bath to vent out as the bathroom is at the end of the room :) - But don't know if that is enough?

Comment: @Indraneel [A typical fart is composed of about ... 21 percent hydrogen ...](https://www.oddee.com/item_98612.aspx).

Comment: @ReneMortensen That comment was for James, not you. Data regarding how much hydrogen gas is produced during charging. And maybe also what concentration is unsafe. This is an EE site after all, we all need numbers!

Comment: Humans produce about 1 litre of hydrogen a day. Some figures for battery out-gassing for UPS rated VRLA cells are available here https://www.cdtechno.com/pdf/ref/41_6739_0112.pdf , those are large batteries (about 4 times the size of those in an APC SUA1000). Those are in mili-litres per hour, so even at the extreme end of that chart 42ml per hour per battery is 24*42=1.008 litres per day so about one human.